# How to Auto-refresh the list of all imported data in MEAN stack. Nodejs+Mongodb+Openshift

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, openshift, mean

I have a form, which a user inserts product data in the databse. When the save button is pressed, the method POST occurs. After the Post, the GET method, is called. Apparently, this works in localhost but on Openshift the POST is executed but the list does't auto refresh.

Server.js (GET, POST method)

```
var ResourcesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,
    serialnumber: String,
    modelno: String,
    description: String
});

var Resources = mongoose.model("Resources", ResourcesSchema);

app.get("/resources", function(req, res){

   Resources.find(function(err, resources)
   {
        res.send(resources);

   });
});

app.post("/resources", function(req, res){
    var resources = new Resources(req.body);
    resources.save(function(err, doc){
        console.log(doc);
        res.json(doc);
    });

});
```

resources.js

```
app.controller("ResCtrl", function($scope, $http) {



        $http.get('/resources')
        .success(function(response) {
            var resource = "";
            $scope.resources = response;
            $scope.resource = "";
        });




    $scope.addResource = function() {
        console.log($scope.resource);
        $http.post('/resources', $scope.resource)
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.resources.push(response);


        });
        $http.get('/resources')
        .success(function(response) {
            var resource = "";
            $scope.resources = response;
            $scope.resource = "";
        });
    };



});
```

Comment: Would you add some basic error handling for both POST and GET `.success(function(response){$scope.resources.push(response);}, function(err){console.log(err)});` There might be some useful info, in case we are getting errors

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Had to do a function named `$scope.all` to retrieve data from the database and i had to call it from inside the `$scope.addResource` function:

```
$scope.addResource = function() {
        console.log($scope.resource);
        $http.post('/resources', $scope.resource)
        .success(function(response){
            $scope.resources.push(response);
            $scope.all();


        });
    };

    $scope.all = function(){
        $http.get('/resources')
        .success(function(response) {
            var resource = "";
            $scope.resources = response;
            $scope.resource = "";
        });
    };
```

so if i make a post to db, the `$scope.all();` will auto-refresh the list

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make GET request after successful POST. You may get not updated data because GET request happens before data saved into database (we are dealing with asynchronous behavior here).

```
app.controller("ResCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/resources')
    .success(function(response) {
        var resource = "";
        $scope.resources = response;
        $scope.resource = "";
    });

    $scope.addResource = function() {
       console.log($scope.resource);
       $http.post('/resources', $scope.resource)
       .success(function(response){
           //$scope.resources.push(response); /*not sure we need this*/

            // will make get call only after data saved successfully
            $http.get('/resources')
           .success(function(response) {
                var resource = "";
                $scope.resources = response;
                $scope.resource = "";
           });

        }, function(err){console.log(err);});

   };

});
```